# Merging 1 or more ODATA responses into 1 JSON message in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, odata, azure-logic-apps

I need some advise how to proceed on the following case.

I am creating a API and this API will call 1 or more SAP ODATA services.
from these ODATA complex responses I want to create my own response and give this back to my API.

How to solve this requirement?
I have been struggling whit some FOR EACH scenario's I [found](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/transforming-json-objects-in-logic-apps), but after deploying these example the Logic App hangs for some reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After reproducing from my end this works fine. I'll try to explain how I achieved your requirement. Below is the whole flow of my Logic app.

[image]

Consider below are the two responses that I'm receiving.

**Input-1**

```
{
   "firstName": "SampleFirstName",
   "lastName": "SampleLastName"
}
```

**Input-2**

```
{
   "email": "sample@sample.com",
   "Tasks": [
      {
         "TaskNo": "1",
         "Date": "2022-08-25"
      },
      {
         "TaskNo": "2",
         "Date": "2022-08-25"
      },
      {
         "TaskNo": "3",
         "Date": "2022-08-25"
      }
   ]
}
```

[image]

In the next step I'm trying to Parse both the inputs

[image]

Below is the JSON Schema for `Parse JSON for Input-1`

```
{
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Below is the JSON Schema for `Parse JSON for Input-2`

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Tasks": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "Date": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "TaskNo": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "TaskNo",
                    "Date"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

You can generate your own schema using `Use sample payload to generate schema` for your Parse JSON action.

[image]

In the next step you can use `Compose` action to have your custom built JSON. Below is how I'm merging both the JSONs.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can map the objects using Select action

[image]

You can reproduce the same from your end using the below codeview.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Input-1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "firstName": "SampleFirstName",
                    "lastName": "SampleLastName"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Input-2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "Tasks": [
                        {
                            "Date": "2022-08-25",
                            "TaskNo": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Date": "2022-08-25",
                            "TaskNo": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "Date": "2022-08-25",
                            "TaskNo": "3"
                        }
                    ],
                    "email": "sample@sample.com"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Input-1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Merged_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "Tasks": "@body('Parse_JSON_for_Input-2')?['Tasks']",
                    "firstName": "@{body('Parse_JSON_for_Input-1')?['firstName']}",
                    "lastName": "@{body('Parse_JSON_for_Input-1')?['lastName']}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON_for_Input-2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON_for_Input-1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Input-1')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "firstName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "lastName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Input-2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_JSON_for_Input-2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Input-2')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Tasks": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Date": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "TaskNo": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "TaskNo",
                                        "Date"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            },
                            "email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON_for_Input-1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```